# React - Trying to render property of object, though it stays "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, render

`console.log(detailtext)` shows me that the data of the object is there, the props seem to work, but I can't display the properties of the object.
Why?

It's a very simple component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class LibraryTextDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const detailtext = this.props.detailview || {};
    console.log("THIS IS THE DETAILTEXT");
    console.log(detailtext);
    const detailviewIds = detailtext.id;
    console.log("THIS IS THE DETAILVIEW ID");
    console.log(detailviewIds);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="covercard">
          <img
            src={detailtext.lead_image_url}
            width={157}
            className="coverdetailimage"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="titledetailcard">{detailtext.title}</div>
        <div className="authordetailcard">{detailtext.author}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LibraryTextDetails;
```

Here is the `console.log`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in an array as `detailview` to your component. The data you see in your console is the data of the first object in the array. Make sure you render `detailview[0]`, and it will work.

**Example**

```
class LibraryTextDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { detailview } = this.props;
    const detailtext = (detailview && detailview[0]) || {};

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="covercard">
          <img
            src={detailtext.lead_image_url}
            width={157}
            className="coverdetailimage"
          />
          <div className="titledetailcard">{detailtext.title}</div>
          <div className="authordetailcard">{detailtext.author}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was unfortunately just a copy/paste issue. Fixed above.

Comment: Works now! Thanks so so much!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing important thing

`detailtext` is array of objects

when you see in `log [{ ... }]` it means it's Array with one object

`log` also displays first object in array below

so correct use would be

```
detailtext[0].lead_image_url
detailtext[0].title
```

and similar or use proxy variable 
or fix the way you send data to this component not to be array but just an object (first in array)

Comment: Alex, thanks so much! Good catch, that might be my problem. How could I missed that... ;) --- Unfortunately though, for `const detailviewIds = detailtext[0].id;` I get a `index_bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at t.value`